# Fourier Transform, convolution

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

I was trying to solve some exam problems when I encountered a really peculiar exercise, that I couldn't figure out, unfortunately:
Find the function $f(x) s.t. f(x) \to 0$ as $|x|\to \infty$, which satisfies the equation (integrals are all from $-\infty,\infty$).

$$\iiint f(y)g_1(z)g_1(t)\delta(x-y-z-t)dydzdt = g_2(x)$$

where
$$g_1(x) =  \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-m)^2}{2\alpha^2} } }{\sqrt{2\pi\alpha^2}},\quad g_2(x) = \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.$$

The solution says that the first triple integral represents the convolution between $f(x) \ast G(x-y)$, where $G(x-y) = g_1 \ast g_1$, namely the convolution of $g_1$ with itself. After having seen this I was able to fully solve the exercise. The problem still remains: how can a human recognize that the first triple integral is a convolution of a convolution. Is it possible to show it in some way, maybe using the Dirac delta properties? I can't come up with a way of putting the first triple integral in the usual form of a convolution ( $\int f(y) G(x-y)dy$, which the solution gives me). I think the delta is there to somehow get rid of two of the integrals (in $dz$ and $dt$). I was thinking of a clever change of variable but couldn't come up with it. Can someone help me with this? Every help is well appreciated ;)

Comment: Just iterate the convolution for a few different functions, it's fairly immediate.  I can do the first two for this particular example and the rest should be obvious. $\int \delta(x - y) f(y)dy$ convolute with $g_1$ to get $\int \int \delta(x-y-z) f(y)g_1(z) dy dz$ etc.

Comment: well I gotta admit  that after your explanation, it now seems kinda obvious. Thank you @mildboson for the help.

Comment: I've followed your strategy: could you say that this is right: let us suppose we have this integral : $\int \int f(z) \cdot \frac{1}{1+y^2}\delta(x-y-z)dydz$. Would you solve it this way:  let's consider f(x), \delta(x), g(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}, then we obtain, by your recursive strategy:                                   
$\int f(z,t)\delta(x-z)dz$, convoluting with $g$ we get: $\int \int f(z)g(y)\delta(x-z-y)dzdy$. Is this what you would do or have I misinterpreted your message?